# Callback protocols - when do we need the double underscore prefix?

Tags: python, mypy

The [mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#callback-protocols) read

> Callback protocols and :py:data:`~typing.Callable` types can be used
> interchangeably. Keyword argument names in :py:meth:`__call__ <object.__call__>` methods must be identical, unless a double
> underscore prefix is used. For example:
>
> ````
> typing_extensions import Protocol
>
> T = TypeVar('T')
>
> class Copy(Protocol):
>     def __call__(self, __origin: T) -> T: ...
>
> copy_a: Callable[[T], T]    copy_b: Copy
>
> copy_a = copy_b  # OK    copy_b = copy_a  # Also OK    ```
> ````

However, this example also works if we remove the double underscore prefix from before `__origin`. E.g.

```
$ cat t.py 
from typing import Callable, TypeVar
from typing_extensions import Protocol

T = TypeVar('T')

class Copy(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, origin: T) -> T: ...

copy_a: Callable[[T], T]
copy_b: Copy

copy_a = copy_b  # OK
copy_b = copy_a  # Also OK
$ mypy t.py 
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

So, this example isn't clear to me. When do we need the double underscore prefix?

Comment: You only need them if an attribute should be subject to name mangling or the language definition defines a special name with double underscores and you want to use that.

Comment: Thanks - is there an example anywhere?

Comment: Check ``reveal_type(copy_a)`` – MyPy infers it to type ``Copy`` since that is what is assigned first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A named parameter can be used in placed of an anonymous parameter, so the Protocol works as a value for the Callable. The first assignment `copy_a = copy_b` silently promotes `copy_a` to a `Copy`, which is then valid to assign to `copy_b: Copy`.

```py
...

copy_a = copy_b  # copy_a is a Copy now!
copy_b = copy_a  # assign copy_a: Copy to copy_b: Copy
reveal_type(copy_a)  # Revealed type is 'aaa_testbed.Copy'
```

Swapping the assignment means `copy_b = copy_a` happens while `copy_a` is still the anonymous type. This triggers the expected error:

```py
...

copy_b = copy_a  # Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Callable[[T], T]", variable has type "Copy")
copy_a = copy_b
```